# Event emitters parameter is undefined for listener Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm very new to Vue.js. I have 3 simple components in my Laravel project, one PostForm to post a tweet, and others to show the post on a timeline. I am using Axios to post and get data from the back-end. When I'm posting a tweet it's getting saved in my database, but when I pass data by event, I get this error.

[image]

PostForm component:

```
<template>  
    <form action="#" class="form-vertical" @submit.prevent="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="body" id="" cols="30" rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Write something likable" v-model="body"></textarea>  
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post it!</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
import eventhub from '../event'
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            body:null
        }
    },
    methods:{
        post(){

            axios.post('posts',{
                body:this.body
            }).then((response)=>{

            eventhub.$emit('post-added', response.body)
                this.body=null
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When I `console.log(response.data)` I am getting everything properly...

[image]

...and then I'm emitting event (post-added) to my timeline component.

Timeline Component:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Timeline</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <postform></postform>
                        <hr>
                        <post v-for="post in posts" :post="post" :key="post.index"></post>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import eventhub from '../event'
import Post from './Post.vue' 
import postform from './PostForm.vue'

export default {
    data(){
        return{
            posts:[]
        }
    } ,
    components:{
        Post,postform
    }
    ,
    methods:{
        addpost(record){

        }
    },
    mounted() {
        eventhub.$on('post-added',this.addpost)
        axios.get('/posts').then((response)=>{
            this.posts=response.data
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

I am catching that post-added event in mounted, and then passing the value to addpost method(record). This is where I am getting this error.

[image: https://snag.gy/Cjlaw6.jpg]

In addpost method when I'm trying to `console/log(record)` it's giving me undefined. I think this is the error, and I have no idea why it's giving me undefined.

[image: https://snag.gy/Hz1Xo3.jpg]

Note in my event.js file which is I'm importing has this code `module.exports = new Vue()` only.

Comment: Since the error occurs inside `addpost()`, it would be helpful to see the code of that method and the value of `record`.

Comment: please share the rest of the code, or replicate it on code sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Here in the below code:

```
eventhub.$emit('post-added', response.body)
```

`response.body` is `undefined`. This is because `body` isn't a field exposed in the response for the request (This response schema is specific to the *axios* client.)<sup>[1](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema)</sup>

Assuming that after making the HTTP POST request, the server returns a response that you'll like to process in the client.

That response data can be retrieved in the `data` field of the response in the following manner.

```
eventhub.$emit('post-added', response.data)
```